Error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.String org.apache.avro.Schema.toString(java.util.Collection, boolean)
Error: when publish AVRO kafka record with kafka client dependency
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.String org.apache.avro.Schema.toString(java.util.Collection, boolean)

Fix: add following:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
    <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.0</version>
</dependency>

